# WCF Workflow hosted on IIS issue

Tags: wcf, iis

I've hosted WCF WF on IIS. From client side I am trying to access service on IIS, but getting such error:

`The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'GetData'. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 197, position 41.`

This is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="DataAccess.SharePoint.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <applicationSettings>
    <DataAccess.SharePoint.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="DataAccess_SharePoint_Officecms_Lists" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://site/_vti_bin/lists.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </DataAccess.SharePoint.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

This is my client app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text"
                    textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" 
                                  />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://server2008/Services/Search.xamlx"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
                contract="SearchService.IService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Could you please verify my configs, and modify and explain what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this message on the server or on the client?  If the message from the client to the server is bigger than the default limit, you need to increase that in your web.config.

You can control your bindings in the web.config by adding this to the system.ServiceModel section:

```
  <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength ="<your max here>"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```